# Qt slot is not called

Tags: qt, slot

I have shortened the code.
I have a main window with a button. The button opens another window to register someone's personnal information.
When I click on "Confirmer" it should trigger the confirmerInformations() slot. However nothing happens.
I don't understand why. I have no error log.

Sorry for the huge code but this problem makes me crazy. 
I don't understand why the slot in the first window works although the slot in the second window with the exact same syntax won't run the method `confirmerInformations`

**main.ccp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Principale fenetrePrincipale;
    fenetrePrincipale.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Principale.h**

```
#ifndef PRINCIPALE_H
#define PRINCIPALE_H

#include<QApplication>
#include<QPushButton>
#include<QBoxLayout>
#include<QGroupBox>


#include"Inscription.h"
#include"Connexion.h"

class Principale: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Principale();
public slots:
    void inscription();
    void connexion();

private:
    QPushButton * boutonInscription;
    QVBoxLayout * vboxPrincipale;
    QVBoxLayout * layoutPrincipal;
    QGroupBox * general;
    QGroupBox* groupPrincipal;


};
#endif // PRINCIPALE_H
```

**Principale.cpp**

```
Principale::Principale()
    {
        setFixedSize(250, 150);
        boutonInscription = new  QPushButton("Ouvrir un nouveau compte bancaire");
        vboxPrincipale = new QVBoxLayout;

        vboxPrincipale->addWidget(boutonInscription);

        general = new QGroupBox("Cliquez sur un bouton");
        general->setLayout(vboxPrincipale);

        layoutPrincipal = new QVBoxLayout;
        layoutPrincipal->addWidget(general);

        setLayout(layoutPrincipal);
        setWindowTitle("Bienvenue dans votre banque");

        connect(boutonInscription, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(inscription()));


    }

    void Principale::inscription()
    {

        Inscription *uneInscription = new Inscription();
        uneInscription->show();

    }
```

**Inscription.h**

```
#ifndef INSCRIPTION_H
#define INSCRIPTION_H
#include<QWidget>
#include<QLineEdit>
#include<QPushButton>
#include<QGroupBox>
#include<QBoxLayout>
#include<QLabel>
#include<QFormLayout>

    class Inscription : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Inscription();
    private:
        // Information personnellses
        QGroupBox* boxInformationsPersonnelles_;
        QFormLayout* formInformationsPersonnelles_;
        QLabel* labelNom_;
        QLineEdit* nom_;


        // Boutons
        QGroupBox* boxBoutons_;
        QHBoxLayout* layoutBoutons_;
        QPushButton* boutonConfirmation_;

        //Layout principal
        QVBoxLayout* layoutPrincipal_;

    public slots:
        void confirmerInformations();
    };
```

**Inscription.cpp**

```
#include"Inscription.h"
#include<QErrorMessage>
#include<QDebug>

Inscription::Inscription(){

    // Box Informations personnelles
        labelNom_ = new QLabel("Nom :");
        nom_ = new QLineEdit();

        boxInformationsPersonnelles_ = new QGroupBox("Vos informations personnelles");
        boxInformationsPersonnelles_->setLayout(formInformationsPersonnelles_);

     // Box boutons
        boutonConfirmation_ = new QPushButton("Confirmer");

        layoutBoutons_ = new QHBoxLayout();
        layoutBoutons_->addWidget(boutonConfirmation_);

        boxBoutons_ = new QGroupBox("Confirmation");
        boxBoutons_->setLayout(layoutBoutons_);


     // Layout principal
        layoutPrincipal_ = new QVBoxLayout();
        layoutPrincipal_->addWidget(boxInformationsPersonnelles_);
        setLayout(layoutPrincipal_);


    // Connexion des boutons
        boutonConfirmation_ = new QPushButton("Confirmer");

        connect(boutonConfirmation_, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(confirmerInformations()));

}

//Slots

void Inscription::confirmerInformations(){
        QErrorMessage* erreurInformationsPersonnelles = new QErrorMessage();
        erreurInformationsPersonnelles->showMessage("Veuillez remplir toutes vos informations personnelles");

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allocate memory twice.

```
boutonConfirmation_ = new QPushButton("Confirmer");
//...
boutonConfirmation_ = new QPushButton("Confirmer");//why?
```

Remove one line.

Explanation. I want to add some short code which you can easily compile on your machine and show the problem:

```
QPushButton *ptr;           //just pointer
ptr = new QPushButton(this);//allocate memory, this is a parent
ptr->setObjectName("ptr");  //object name to find it in future
qDebug() << ptr;            //show ptr
ptr = new QPushButton;      //allocate memory again, but without parent
qDebug() <<  connect(ptr,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(echo()));
                            //show that connection was succesfull
qDebug() << "new ptr"<< ptr << "old ptr" << this->findChildren<QPushButton *>("ptr");
                            //show new and old ptrs
```

Output:

```
QPushButton(0x28d726a8, name = "ptr") //our old ptr
true                                  //connection succesfull
new ptr QPushButton(0x28d726e8) old ptr (QPushButton(0x28d726a8, name = "ptr") )
//pay attention that new ptr and old has different adresses and names, it is 2 different buttons.
```

Conclusion: in your code you use old button which was not connected, so you slot never calls.

Comment: Could you please add the logic to your answer why it was happening? In short, `layoutBoutons_->addWidget(boutonConfirmation_);` was adding the leaked pointer to the UI and the connection was made to the overridden pointer.

Comment: Sure, no hurry. Just that the readers do not get the wrong impression of doing this double construction on its own can cause this. Thanks. :)

Comment: @lpapp Already done. I added short compilable code and explanation